# How to animate text color of a UILabel like a progress bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, text, uilabel

I'm trying to change the text color of a UILabel progressively from left to right. I found I can use UIView's animation:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:_label duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    _label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
} completion:nil];
```

But the question is there isn't an option for my case: progressively from left to right.

Then I found a way to change the text color letter by letter by calling:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(yourSelector) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)yourSelector
{
    [_string setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]} range:NSMakeRange(_index, 1)];
    [_label setAttributedText:_string];
    _index++;
}
```

But the question here is that I want the animation be more like letter by letter but each letter has animation as well, like there are two labels with different colors placed in the same position (black covers red) and just animate a mask from left to right to hide the black label so that the red label shows progressively.

So is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: ahhh you want it to be like a progress bar? Not "letter by letter"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve it, follow below steps:

- Create 2 `UILabel` (`trackLabel` and `progressLabel`).
- `trackLabel` have `blackColor` and `progressLabel` have `redColor`.
- Make `progressLabel` overlap `trackLabel`, same leading, top and bottom.
- Give `trackLabel` full width with text and `progressLabel` 0 width.
- Set `progressLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;`
- When you need to animate progress, increase width of `progressLabel`.

For more detail, you can check [my demo project](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/progress-label).

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: The question I got is when I need some paddings at the left/right and make it center aligned, then the above label cannot position it's text right above the bottom label

Comment: In this case, you should calculate the text width to give a suitable leading constraint for progress label.